# Macro to run through each datapoint in data validation list

Tags: vba, validation, macros

I want to code a Macro which runs through each data point in the two data validation lists which are on different sheets. Here's the code I wrote:

```
 Sub selfrefpop()

    Dim cell1           As Excel.Range
    Dim cell2           As Excel.Range
    Dim SO              As Excel.Range
    Dim AF              As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV1           As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV2           As Excel.Range
    Dim activews        As Worksheet
    Dim dashboard       As Worksheet

      Set activews = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

      Set dashboard = Sheets("Dashboard")

      Set SO = activews.Range("D8")

      Set AF = dashboard.Range("L17")

      Set rgDV1 = activews.Range(SO.Validation.Formula1)

      With dashboard
        Set rgDV2 = .Range(AF.Validation.Formula1)
      End With

        For Each cell1 In rgDV1
            rgDV1.Value = cell1.Value

            For Each cell2 In rgDV2
                rgDV2.Value = cell2.Value
            Next
        Next

End Sub
```

I am getting an error at line:

```
 Set rgDV2 = .Range(AF.Validation.Formula1)
```

Error says "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed, error 1004"

I know its a referencing error. But having a problem in figuring out the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the validation formula in dashboard.Range("L17")?

Comment: It's linked to set of values

Comment: Okay. What is the actual validation formula in "L17" though? If I don't know the formula I can't help you debug your error

Comment: It's a list of values ranging from 2.5%-15%

Comment: Okay, so the formula is a list of values like `=2.5%,4%,6%,10%,15%` and not a range reference to cells containing that list, correct?

Comment: Correct. I can reference it though, if that solves the prb.

Comment: I added an answer. If that solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `Set rgDV2 = .Range(AF.Validation.Formula1)`, but `AF.Validation.Formula1` is not a range. If you make the validation formula a range referencing your list of percentages it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The problem is that if I do that, I get the same error for rgDV1.

Comment: What is the validation formula for rgDV1? If it's not a range reference it will give you that error. Adding screen shots to your question would be very helpful.

Comment: @user2279030 Do you still need help with this?